# How to find the mean of all variables for specific rows in R?

Tags: r, mean

I have a data file like this:

```
Code    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1       130 965 36  99  64
2       99  311 52  64  29
3       133 647 34  92  49
4       122 460 44  85  43
5       115 266 35  62  32
6       110 486 34  66  41
7       111 689 44  67  31
8       115 274 57  72  26
9       122 112 45  86  45
10      124 214 41  84  45
11      11  133 292 41  101
12      108 174 59  59  12
13      124 346 52  94  37
14      14  125 239 53  82
```

And what to find the mean of Code 1 to 10 in every column, excluding 11 to 14 of the equation.
How could I do it?

Comment: `sapply(df[1:10,-1], mean)`?

Comment: Also `rowMeans(df[1:10, -1])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should match your question. Using `dplyr`

The idea is you need to filter to get only the rows you needed then apply the mean functions across the columns you want.

```r
data <- structure(list(Code = 1:14, V1 = c(130L, 99L, 133L, 122L, 115L, 
  110L, 111L, 115L, 122L, 124L, 11L, 108L, 124L, 14L), V2 = c(965L, 
    311L, 647L, 460L, 266L, 486L, 689L, 274L, 112L, 214L, 133L, 174L, 
    346L, 125L), V3 = c(36L, 52L, 34L, 44L, 35L, 34L, 44L, 57L, 45L, 
      41L, 292L, 59L, 52L, 239L), V4 = c(99L, 64L, 92L, 85L, 62L, 66L, 
        67L, 72L, 86L, 84L, 41L, 59L, 94L, 53L), V5 = c(64L, 29L, 49L, 
          43L, 32L, 41L, 31L, 26L, 45L, 45L, 101L, 12L, 37L, 82L)), row.names = c(NA, 
            -14L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
# Full data mean for every column
data %>%
  summarize(across(.cols = starts_with("V"), .fns = mean))
#>         V1       V2 V3       V4   V5
#> 1 102.7143 371.5714 76 73.14286 45.5

# Only include Code from 1 to 10
data %>%
  filter(Code >= 1 & Code <= 10) %>%
  # calculate the mean for all columnstart with V
  summarize(across(.cols = starts_with("V"), .fns = mean))
#>      V1    V2   V3   V4   V5
#> 1 118.1 442.4 42.2 77.7 40.5

# If you want to include the list of Code was included in the calculation
data %>%
  filter(Code >= 1 & Code <= 10) %>%
  summarize(
    code_included = list(Code),
    across(.cols = starts_with("V"), .fns = mean))
#>                   code_included    V1    V2   V3   V4   V5
#> 1 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 118.1 442.4 42.2 77.7 40.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

#### A Base R approach using lapply

```r
# filter data with Code between 1 & 10 - exlcude the first column then
# apply mean function
lapply(data[data$Code >= 1 & data$Code <= 10, -1], mean)
#> $V1
#> [1] 118.1
#> 
#> $V2
#> [1] 442.4
#> 
#> $V3
#> [1] 42.2
#> 
#> $V4
#> [1] 77.7
#> 
#> $V5
#> [1] 40.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, and if I wanted to now find the meanof others variables, for example I want to find the means of {3, 11, 12, 13, 14}, i just change the numbers? like "lapply(data[data$Code = 3 & data$Code >= 11, -1], mean)" ?

Comment: Yes! Another way is using `%in%` like this
`lapply(data[data$Code %in% c(3, 11, 12, 13, 14), -1], mean)`